# iPhone Lock over web

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have asked this question before but i think i was not much clear that is the  reason why i could not get exact answer to what i want.

i want to lock and unlock my iphone over a web server (i enter the passcode and the web server will check if it is valid then i will be authenticated else message shown i entered wrong passcode) and not to authentication of web server So;

-is it possible?
-if yes how?

Where should i start from? i am very much stuck with this one problem from last one month. Can any one guide me to do this how?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. (Unless you create something that mimics MobileMe and/or Exchange server as those can lock and wipe iPhones, unlocking isn't possible though.)

Comment: Okay, if this is not possible then how should i do the locking and unlocking of iphone?

Look, i have tried to find some solution for this only problem , 

i started with the iphone lock and unlock, i came to know that the lock is pretty much handled by the sleep mode functionality. while there are these two functions UIApplication delegate , ApplicationWillResignActive: and ApplicationWillBecomeResign: if i am not wrong.

Comment: But then there was this other problem that i cannot do user authentication of iphone as there is no API provided by the iphone so either we use the functionality of iphone's unlocking how they do it or if i develop custom application that can not be allowed by the Apple as we are interfering with the OS functionality. But my question is still there how will atleast i do that?

Comment: Anyways, i then shifted to mac as there were authorization n authentication services API available there but the problem is that either i develop a carbon application or cocoa , reason carbon because i found a sample code example that i can take help from it and understand it but then there was portability issues as if i first understand low level C programming to understand that problem and then implement it as  cocoa application...
and now finally i moved to do it with this web authentication process but now you say that this unlocking is not possible!!